# How to get companies from AngelList API

Tags: java, url, web-crawler

Is it possible to use the AngelList API to get the entire list of companies (startups) inside the AngelList website without knowing the ID of all of them?

Or, is there a way to get all of the company IDs?

I'm trying a JSON parser with random URL, because the AngelList URLs are randomly used for location, market and other.

I would like to obtain all the AngelList startups and companies in a txt file

```
for (int h = 1612; h<=1885; h++){
    do {
        // change the URL as per the requirement and also paginating it
        String libURL = "https://api.angel.co/1/tags/" + h + "/startups?page="
                + i;
        InputStream in = URI.create(libURL).toURL().openStream();
        // writing each page into a seperate file
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                "/Users/Fabio/Desktop/FilesAngellist/file" + i + ".txt");
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }// end of while
        if (i == 1) {
            DownloadJobJson db = new DownloadJobJson(); // code to pull
                                                        // "last_page" value
                                                        // from json file
            pagenumber = db.DownloadJobJson1();
        }// end of if
        i = i + 1;
    } while (i <= pagenumber);// end of do-while()
}
```

This is the code of the JSON downloader from AngelList URL

Comment: 1) it's probably againsta angellist's Terms of Use. Have you asked their support? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm waiting for a response from the support, i'm trying with a JSON parser but it's very hard to do because the AngelList URL are randomly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved using linkedin j project

Comment: Would you mind describing your approach a bit more in detail? Thank you

Comment: @JannisHanke With this wrapper i've taked some data about companies on LinkedIn without know too much LinkedIn API.